# ManagementEventWatcher losting events in C#

Tags: c#, managementeventwatcher

I'm developing an application that uses `ManagementEventWatcher` to monitor `USB` events. The code works properly but in some cases the program lost some `USB events`. What is the correct way to list all events from USB?

I'm using the follow code, I'm using two queries for monitor attach and detach from usb. I need to monitor a many USB ports.

**USB Monitor**

```
    ManagementEventWatcher watchUSBattach = new ManagementEventWatcher();
    ManagementEventWatcher watchUSBDettach = new ManagementEventWatcher();

    WqlEventQuery queryUsbAttach = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 ");
    watchUSBattach.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watchUSBEventAdd);
    watchUSBattach.Query = queryUsbAttach;
    watchUSBattach.Start();

    WqlEventQuery queryUsbDettach = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 3");
    watchUSBDettach.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watchUSBEventDettach);
    watchUSBDettach.Query = queryUsbDettach;
    watchUSBDettach.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar thing when monitoring for usb device insertion or removal. Example code below. When the `WithinInterval` property is set to 1ms then I do not miss the events but instead I suffer an unreasonable CPU load in WMIProviderHost and the associated service. If I set it to a more reasonable value like 3 seconds then I miss Deletion/Creation events if they occur together from the same device too quickly (for example if the device resets itself). Perhaps with your query the default `WithinInterval` is too long and is causing events to be dropped?

```
WqlEventQuery q;
var scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2") 
  {Options = {EnablePrivileges = true}};

q = new WqlEventQuery
{
  EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent",
  WithinInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1),
  Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'"
};
InsertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
InsertWatcher.EventArrived += (sender, args) =>
{
  var instance = (ManagementBaseObject) args.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
  RaiseInserted(new PlugEventArgs {DevicePath = (string) instance["__PATH"]});
};
InsertWatcher.Start();
```